# Auth0 Facebook user_id and access_token - Retrieving page_id

Tags: facebook, reactjs, express, facebook-graph-api, auth0

I have a React application where I'm able to link accounts from different social medias to the main username and password account. I linked my Facebook account where I manage several other page and I assumed that with the user_id and access_token that comes back from Auth0 I'd be able to access my pages but I haven't been able to do that. Does my Auth0 app need to be reviewed by Facebook before I get access ?

When I go to the Graph API Explorer, paste in the access_token from Auth0 and try to access ${user_id}/accounts, I get the following Debug message:

```
The field 'accounts' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants either the 'pages_show_list' or 'manage_pages' permission.
```

even tho I clearly granted those permission on Auth0->Connections->Social.

What am I missing here ?

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to be able to ask a user that does not have a role in the app for those permissions - then yes, of course you have to submit for review.

Comment: _“even tho I clearly granted those permission on Auth0->Connections->Social”_ - you don’t _grant_ permissions there, you just configure which permissions your app should _ask_ the user for on login. Did you go through the login flow with the account you are testing this with? Did it ask for access to your pages in the login dialog?

Comment: Hmm, I just re-checked and when I'm prompted to review the Info I'll provide, it only says Public Profile. Is there another way to tell it to grant access to Pages as well ?

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app? _"Is there another way to tell it to grant access to Pages as well ?"_ - well you'd have to check the auth0 docs.

Comment: The user I'm testing with is the one I registered the developer account with on Facebook. Going into Settings->Apps on Facebook I can see two apps there: one that I made with Facebook and the one that I allowed through Auth0. Now, going back to the Graph API Explorer I can see all my connections just fine using the app I made with Facebook but the app I made with Auth0 is not available from the Application drop down menu. Any suggestions ? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: _“but the app I made with Auth0 is not available from the Application drop down menu”_ – well that doesn’t sound like you actually have a role in the app …